# Display Word Document inside ASP.Net page

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

I want to display a word Document, which is sitting on my IIS. I want to display the whole document as is, inside a iFrame on my aspx page.

I know I can use MS Word Libs, but I cannot install Word on Server where application will be hosted, (Correct me if I am wrong: I cannot use just dlls without installing MS Word on Server).

How can I display the word document in my iFrame?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way would be to include the [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer).

Other ways could be to use [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial) to convert Word to PDF and then use Aspose.Pdf.Kit to convert PDF to images and then display the images online.

Answer (score 0):

PowerTools for Open XML contains an open source, free implementation of a conversion from DOCX to HTML formatted with CSS.  The module HtmlConverter.cs supports all paragraph, character, and table styles, fonts and text formatting, numbered and bulleted lists, images, and more.  See http://bit.ly/1bclyg9