# Displaying word doc in browswe using asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok so basically i want to display a word doc in the browser as readyonly no editing required access from file and display.... im not particular about it being a word doc but i want the display to inherit text formatting and maybe even include pics if possible. I have currently used the following set of code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["Link"] != null)
            {
                String link = Session["Link"].ToString();
                ApplicationClass appClass = new ApplicationClass();
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                object visible = true;
                object readOnly = true;
                object fileName = link;
                Document wordDoc = appClass.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref visible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            TextArea1.InnerText = wordDoc.Content.Text;

            appClass.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        }
        else
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = WCGSQL.showdata("select max(Date) from WeeklyMsg");
            if (ds != null)
            {
                String MaxDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                ds = WCGSQL.showdata("select * from WeeklyMsg where Date='" + MaxDate + "'");
                String link = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                String Path = "i:\\Website/WebSite3/WMSG/" + link;
                ApplicationClass appClass = new ApplicationClass();
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                object visible = true;
                object readOnly = true;
                object fileName = Path;
                Document wordDoc = appClass.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref visible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                TextArea1.InnerText = wordDoc.Content.Text;

                appClass.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            }
        }
    }
```

Which worked file for an asp website but when i use it on a asp web app it give me the following error

```
Error   2   Task could not find "AxImp.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed   WebApplication2
```

really open to any ideas that can fix this even external apps (it would be best if it is free creating site for non profit org so got a really limited budget)

thx in advance
Mark

Comment: what is the value of `Path` when you debug this line `String Path = "i:\\Website/WebSite3/WMSG/" + link;` ?

Comment: oh sorry forgot to mention my file names are being saved in a table in datable so basically the `+link` part will be the file name as which is variable as for the rest it is constant and am using reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; for the code above

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578013/display-word-document-inside-asp-net-page

Comment: thx for the info but i did see the above forum link before my problem is im using iis to generate the url as so http://localhost:2341/txt/stories.docx which with google doc looks like this http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://localhost:2341/txt/stories.docx&embedded=true but when i run it shows a error from google docs http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://localhost:2341/txt/stories.docx&embedded=true and a click here which leads me to download the file which i do not want i just require to display it is there anything im doing wrong?